# Reading bitrate of MP3 from server

Tags: vb.net, header, mp3

**This question is related to VB.NET 2010**

I'm trying to get some information about an mp3 file on a server. So I tried using a System.Net.WebClient and .OpenRead() to read 4 bytes at position 16 from the stream. Turns out the stream doesn't support seeking.

So how should I get the bitrate of an mp3 file on a server, without downloading the whole file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stream from the server until you get a valid frame header, and then disconnect.

MP3 files sometimes start with ID3 tags, so you don't know exactly at what position you can read the frame header.  You must begin reading the file until you find one.  If you don't find a frame header within 128KB or so, disconnect as you probably don't have an MP3 file at all.

Comment: Hmm but how would I identify it in the 128kB?

Comment: You need to actually parse the frame header.

Comment: Sorry for late response ... could you give me some example ?

Comment: @MichaelAntonio http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html  Altneratively, let FFmpeg figure it out for you.

Comment: ahaaaa good link !!!! that explain all what i want. Now i know where to start. Thanks a lot, brad